# House numbers on Mathematics Street

Tags: mathematics, pattern

House numbers on *Mathematics Street* follow a pattern.
Green blocks are empty spaces where no houses are built.

[image]

---

***What are the house numbers of red and yellow blocks?***
***What is the reason behind empty spaces (green blocks) on the street?***

Comment: I can tell you the last 2 digits of red & yellow :P

Comment: Haha. That's 90% of the job done!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First:

> Create a sequence with the values of the first row and the reversed order of the second, so `r, 3415, 4392, ..., 3326, 4543, g, g, g, ..., y`

Then

> The last two digits of each value are the `n`th digit of PI: `r,r,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,...,1,9,y,y`. The missing values are `r=..14` and `y=..71`

And

> Each of the first two digits of every value are the [number of letters in the words formed by the digital recitation of Pi in the English language.](https://oeis.org/A107488): `r,r,3,4,4,3,...` (one, five, nine, two, ...). The missing values are `r=34..` and `y=53..`

Red and Yellow:

> Are therefore `r = 3414` and `y = 5371`

The Greens:

> Are invalid because `5538, 5332, 5479` are repetitions, and therefore would not constitute valid house numbers on the same street.

Comment: @chandanr777 Should be correct now, counting is hard :)

Comment: Haha. Yes. It's correct now. From my experience, good logicians usually make silly counting errors :)

Comment: I always thought rot13(gung gur svefg qvtvg bs cv jnf n 3) :-)